# How can I optimize my Angular Http Post?

Tags: angular, angular-http

I have to make a Http post call to my rest service and it will pull a large amount of data at once. When I make the call right now the pages freezes for about 1.5 seconds and it display all the data on the page and I can scroll. But until the data is all back the browser is not responsive.

Is there any way to prevent this? Is there a way I can start rendering the page as I get the data and not have to wait for all the data back?

Here is the call I have on my service.

```
getListItems(topicType: string, topicStatus?: number) {
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}),
          options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
    let   body = 'jwt=' + this.tempToken + '&type=' + topicType;
    if(topicStatus !== undefined) {
      body += '&status=' + topicStatus;
    }
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'read/topicslist', body, options).map((res) => res.json());
 }
```

And on my component I store the result set on an object that is used to display on the template.

Comment: You can use something equivalent to [infinite scroll](https://github.com/metafizzy/infinite-scroll) (*there are others out there*). At the end of each page (where scroll stops) you then get another chunk of data. It is similar to how Facebook works when you scroll through the feed.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the post to get chunks of data. and when you scroll down another post is sent to get the next chunk

Comment: I was trying to see if there any other way to avoid this (making changes to my rest service :) but it looks like I may have to do it ). 

My return object has about 12,000 records, and when I run the query on the DB I get the results in 1 ms. 

Does using the *ngFor on my object

Answer (score 0):

Their no silver bullet to solve these kind large data sets issue. you can follow different approach and methods to mitigate issue. There are lot way to solve this issue but your solution will be depended on what are you doing with your data.

As per your question I understand that you need show multiple user(similar data sets) information and User will scroll to see more information.

you can design like below

1) Add start and page limit to your Ajax call.

Instead of fetching all records, get number records based on your screen size and each record width and height on the UI. 
If your able show around 10 records on screen put page limit as 20 records.

2) Once user started scrolling you can fetch reaming data using virtual scrolling.
I am using virtual scroll in my project it working fine.
http://rintoj.github.io/angular2-virtual-scroll/